# How to print byte in unsign format in Java

Tags: java, int, unsigned-integer

I need to print a variable of type `byte` in an unsigned format. How do I do that?

Comment: public static int unsignedToBytes(byte b) {
        return b & 0xFF;
      }

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please give an example of what you want.

Comment: @Neigyl: put that in an answer.  You'll get more rep that way.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying you are starting with a signed int and want the absolute value?  You could do something like this:

```
    byte b = Byte.parseByte("-9");
    int i = (int) b;

    System.out.println(Math.abs(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just written that method for you.

```
public static String printUnsignedByte(byte b){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(b>0){
        sb.insert(0, b%2==0?0:1);
        b>>=1;
    }
    for(int i = 8-sb.length(); i>0; i--){
        sb.insert(0,0);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

EDIT: But it does not cover 2's complement's format. Do you need that as well?
EDIT2: Check out:

```
Integer.toBinaryString(2)
```

it covers 2es compliment for negative values, but the output is too long, it pribts 4 bit. Just shorten this with substring and you are done.

Edit 3: My final solution.

```
public static String printUnsignedByte(byte b){
    if(b>0){
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(Integer.toBinaryString(b));
        for(int i = 8-ret.length(); i>0; i--){
            ret.insert(0,0);
        }
        return ret.toString();
    }else{
        return Integer.toBinaryString(b).substring(24);
    }
}
```